# MySQL insert ignore, on duplicate key update, with condition

Tags: mysql

I want to insert or update a record in a table. If it doesn't exist, it should be inserted. If it exists, then I only want to update the record if a certain condition is met. Is there a way to do this using a single `INSERT` statement? Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test1 SELECT 1 id, now() dt;
ALTER TABLE test1 ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
INSERT IGNORE INTO test1 (id, dt) VALUES
 (1, '2023-02-06 13:00:00')
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dt = VALUES(dt) WHERE dt = somedatetime;
-- i.e. always insert, but only update dt if existing dt value is something specific
```

I know I can do this using a transaction, I'm just wondering if something like this can be done in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying things out while writing the question and I found this to be one solution:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO test1 (id, dt)
                  SELECT 1, '2023-02-06 13:00:00'
                    FROM test1
                   WHERE (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE id = 1))
                      OR (id = 1 AND dt = somedatetime)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dt = VALUES(dt);
```